# How to wrap image height according to text length

Tags: android, xml, image

I have made an Quiz App in Android and in that I used this Layout to display question and answers,

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/ans_tab"  //This is the Image for both question and answer
              android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/ques1" 
          android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:text="@string/ques1"/>

<RadioGroup android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/quesoptn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

<RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/ques1_1" 
             android:checked="false" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

<RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/ques1_2"
             android:checked="false" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

<RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/ques1_3"
             android:checked="false" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

<RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/ques1_4"
             android:checked="false"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

</RadioGroup> 

</LinearLayout>
```

And I am fetching question and answers from my database randomly and here my problem is when some times question fetched from database are short in length then the Image is not getting wrapped according to that. And It looks awkward when question is short and Image height is longer than question answer portion. Its looks ok when question length is long.

So, My question is how to wrap Image height only when question length is short ?

This is how it looks when question size is short,

[image]

And When Question length is long then it looks ok,

[image]

So, please help me how to wrap the Image when question length is short. I don't think it can be done through `xml`. So, Is there any way to do it programmatically in Android ?

Comment: I dont get it, both images have gap. Just one of them has smaller gap

Comment: Looks like the problem is with your background drawable, `ans_tab`. Is that an image or a shape?

Comment: @shoerat thats an image

Comment: put minHeight for the question

Comment: @invisbo that I dont want the `large gap` so, please tell me is there any way ?

Comment: @mihail Can you please explain it through example

Comment: I want to know how to reduce the height of the image programmatically

Comment: Maybe this one help you, add  android:gravity="center" to your radio group

Comment: add `android:minHeight="100dp"` to the ques1 TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insted of giving background image make a shape in xml

Here is a sample ans_tab.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#FF8800"
        android:startColor="#FFBB33" />

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />

</shape>
```

Put this to res/drawable/ans_tab.xml and remove the original image file.

The result should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you try 9 patch image ?? You can set a 9 patch image instead of normal image on the background so that it can fit according to your post.Also did you try  android:layout_width="wrap_content" ??

Comment: You can set minimum height as well if you know your smallest question height or set 150 dp

Comment: I have posted my `xml` here you can see it and as far i know `wrap_content` is used to wrap the content according to the length(size) of content and my Image height in large so it will wrap the content according to image size.

Comment: I have mentioned every thing in my post so please first read that I am fetching question from database randomly so how can i know about the size of question...hmmm..

Comment: did you try to use 9-patch image??

Comment: I dont know exactly what is 9-patch image. but my image is not 9-patch

Comment: can i make my image 9-patch ?

Comment: Yes. you can make it 9 patch

Answer (score 0):

> Use 9 patch image it will be expand automatically according to your content